# Differentiability implies continuity -- possibly pedantic question about the common proof

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, continuity

The common proof that differentiability implies continuity arrives at this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to a} [f(x) - f(a)] = 0$$

I'm failing to see the simple justification for moving to the next step, which seems to be essentially this:

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) - \lim_{x\to a} f(a) = 0$$

Intuitively, it makes sense, and I'm sure an epsilon-delta proof can be furnished. But as a matter of simple limit laws (the subtraction law in this case), the above assumes $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, no? Curiously, the authors who use this proof consider it important in other contexts to beat home the fact that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, which they do by using the continuity of **f**. In this case, they can't use the continuity of **f**, for the continuity of **f** is precisely what's under question. So what are they using?

By the way, I understand the final steps of the proof:

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(a)$$
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$$

Comment: The existence of the limit is independent of the addition of constants, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists if and only if $\lim\limits_{x\to a} [f(x) +c]$ exists, for any constant $c$; that is immediate from the limit laws. Take $c = -f(a)$.

Comment: Daniel, I'm failing to see how it's immediately implied by the limit laws, but I'm hoping it is. The limit laws get worded as "IF (the individual limits exist), THEN (...) = (...)." The calculus books I have don't cover $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x) + c]$ as a special case -- they do cover $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x) + g(x)]$, where, for instance, f(x) = 1/x and g(x) = -1/x don't have limits at 0 but f(x)+g(x) does have a limit at 0, showing that the existence of a limit for the sum doesn't necessarily imply the existence of the individual limits. Perhaps they ought to give f(x)+c as a special case?

Comment: The special case $g(x)  \equiv \pm c$ takes you from the existence of $\lim f(x)$ to the existence of $\lim [f(x)+c]$ or vice versa. The slightly more general observation is that under the condition that $\lim g(x)$ exists, then $\lim [f(x)+g(x)]$ exists if and only if $\lim f(x)$ exists. It's probably worth a remark in the text pointing that out.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, it would be helpful if they pointed it out. I can understand someone like Rudin cutting corners (he does so with this proof) because he has a more specialized audience, but these are beginner calculus books I'm trying to study.

Answer (score 3):

Good question.  You're not just being pedantic--you can and should make sure that every step of the proof is $100$% logically sound.

They start out with the assumption that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} [f(x) - f(a)]$ exists and equals $0$.
Then, note that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(a) = f(a)$ because $f(a)$ is just a constant.  Moreover,
$$
f(x) = [f(x) - f(a)] + f(a)
$$
That means **by sum of limits** that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists, and
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} [f(x) - f(a)] + \lim_{x \to a} f(a)
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) - \lim_{x \to a} f(a) = 0.
$$
This is a fairly common observation so most proofs may just go from the first assumption directly to the conclusion.  Anyways, the point is that $f(a)$ is just constant, so that part of the limit necessarily exists.

Comment: Ah, there it is. I understood that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(a) = f(a)$. It's the simple algebraic trick that I was missing: $f(x) = [f(x) - f(a)] + f(a)$ This lets us use limit addends known to exist. That single equation makes everything crystal clear -- much better than the two or three sentences of hand-waving "intuitive English" explanation that some authors offer (e.g., in THE CALCULUS LIFESAVER).